# Can Objective C properties have parameters when accessing them?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties

For example, I've seen `self.someProperty`, but I have never seen `self.someProperty(someParameter)`.

This is a little bit unclear.

Say I have a property `pinImage` -- well, I think it'd be cool to do something like:

```
self.image(@"SomeImage.png");
```

However, that's just not possible, is it?

A property in Objective-C is always in the form of `theObject.property`. It never has parameters.

I am aware that `@property` means you create the `setProperty` and `property` methods. That means the `setProperty` will ALWAYS have one parameter and the `self.property` will always have no parameters.

I am just trying to make sure.

Comment: Whilst it's not clear to me what you're asking, I think it may be possible that you haven't yet grasped what properties are for in Objective-C. My best suggestion is to read the Properties section in [Scott Stevenson's awesome Objective-C tutorial](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/).

Comment: I think the votes to close are a bit hasty. It's a valid question just a little hard to understand at first. As Jonathan guessed, I think the OP just doesn't yet get the concept of properties. Nothing wrong with that - let's try to explain it. That's what this site is for, right? I up-voted to counteract some of the harshness - between the subject and the body, it's a complete and relevant question.

Comment: @Joshua Well said! After reading your comment, I've changed my vote to an upvote. And yes, let's not close this over-hastily.

Comment: I really think that, for this question to be useful and more than idle wondering, it needs some expansion. What prompted the idea of arguments on property accesses? Did you see something similar in another language? Is there an expected/desired purpose or effect? What did you read while trying to figure this out yourself? ***Did you try it***, and what happened? Given more than "I had this thought and posted it", I'd be willing to vote to re-open. @Joshua @Johnathan

Comment: It got closed as I feared. I just cast the final re-open vote needed.

Comment: Stop downvoting please people?  The OP was just confused about properties, no need to downvote.  I also cast to reopen as now it's a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: It's indeed a stupid question. My motivation is public function is effectively like property. For example, if you have a collection of type NSArray * someArray. Then it seems to make sense to do someArray.itemAt(5), for example. I just need to make sure that it is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand what a property actually is.  Suppose you declare a property like this:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *someLabel;
```

When you synthesize it (`@synthesize someLabel;`), you're actually making a method, though it's hidden, that looks something like this:

```
-(void)setSomeLabel:(UILabel *)aSomeLabel {
    if (someLabel != aSomeLabel)
    {
        [someLabel release];
        someLabel = aSomeLabel;
        [someLabel retain];
    }
}
```

So yes, there is a parameter, but it's hidden.

Comment: For completeness, the synthesized methods are "accessor" methods, particularly a "setter" and "getter". Getters don't take parameters because you're asking it to return the value of the property; setters take a single argument: the new value you want the property to take.

Comment: I sorry.  I didn't make that clear enough, I thought it was implied that the getter simply returned the ivar.

Comment: That clarification was for the OP's benefit. :-) He seems not yet to grasp this completely. I blame Objective-C 2.0 properties and @synthesize ... lazy kids and their lazy syntax. ;-)

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. However, in vb.net property can be a function too.

Comment: Objective-C 2.0 kind of obscures its inner workings if you're learning it from 2.0 on. Prior to 2.0, @property and @synthesize didn't exist so you had to roll all your own accessors. This "convenience' has made it harder, I think, for those new to the platform to grasp properties and accessors the Objective-C way (or at all). Didn't mean to suggest you were a complete dev newbie, Jim ... but it did kind of seem that way. :-)